# Fastest way of finding eigenvectors from eigenvalues

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the eigenvalue of a matrix of large dimensions, I want to know if there is a fast way of finding the corresponded eigenvectors?

Comment: Solving the linear system $(A-\lambda I) x=0$ is too slow?

Comment: Yes it is, and not always possible. Generally solving linear systems is a difficult and time consuming task. I would suggest you look up "Inverse Power Method". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration

Comment: since $A-\lambda I$ is singular and the dimension of A is very large, I do not know if there is any better numerical methods except for Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @oria what is meant by "not always possible" ?

Comment: Usually you get the eigenvalue with the eigenvector, or get the eigenvector first and then estimate the eigenvalue (e.g. with a Rayleigh quotient). If you really did get the eigenvalue first, then you are trying to solve $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ one way or another. In large dimensions this would typically be done with an iterative method, but as I said initially, such iterative methods can usually be adjusted to become simultaneous eigenvalue-eigenvector solvers.

Comment: There are iterative methods, such as the elegant jacobi-method. If the solution is needed exactly (not numerically), there is barely something better than gauss-elimination

Comment: @OriaGruber Thanks. Actually the context of my problem is that I do not know what A is but only the similar matrix of A which is easier to obtain the eigenvalues. But since the eigenvectors of A and its similar matrix corresponding to the same eigenvalue might not be the same, I cannot simply apply the power method.

Comment: If $A=PBP^{-1}$ and $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $Px$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: As an aside, this technique is very useful. For example, suppose $A$ is self-adjoint with respect to $(x,y)_Q \equiv (x,Qy)$ for a positive definite $Q$. Then $QA$ is symmetric. $QA$ is of course not similar to $A$, but because $QA$ is symmetric, $Q^{1/2} A Q^{-1/2}$ is also symmetric, and *is* similar to $A$. Thus self-adjoint eigenproblems are equivalent to symmetric eigenproblems, once you have identified $Q$ and calculated $Q^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Ian I see it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the fastest way but recently Denton et al. showed that (https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795, Lemma 2)

$$
|v_{i,j}|^2\prod_{k=1;k\ne i}^n(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(A))=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(M_j))
$$

where

- A is an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i(A)$ and normed eigenvectors $v_i$,
- and the elements of each eigenvector are $v_{i,j}$,
- and $M_j$ is the $n − 1 \times n − 1$ submatrix of A that results from deleting the jth column and the jth row, with eigenvalues $\lambda_k(M_j)$.

Comment: That might not be the fastest one but certainly a really interesting one!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Finding Eigenvectors: Fast & Nontraditional way](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Finding-Eigenvectors-Fast-Nontraditional-Approach) or the [arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06203) for fast and Nontraditional approach without using the Gaussian-Jordan elimination process.

When the matrix is diagonalizable (There is a way to check that) and has a spectrum of two, there is no need to evaluate eigenvectors at all since they already appear as nonzero column vectors of certain matrices that we would like to call *The eigenmatrix*. We have given a general theory for diagonalizable and nondiagonalizable matrices as well.

You have access to the part of the preprint under the same link.